# Jquery: Checking to see if div contains <a href class="nodeSel">, then add style to div

Tags: jquery

I'm tring to add class to div, which contains `<a href class="nodeSel">` marker:

1. no active inside
   `<div id="menufirst" class="dtNode"><img src="empty.gif"><img alt="" src="empty.gif"><img asrc="empty.gif"><a href="http://www.sample1.com" class="node">title1</a> </div>`
2. active inside
   `<div id="menufirst" class="dtNode"><img src="empty.gif"><img alt="" src="empty.gif"><img src="empty.gif"><a href="http://www.sample2.com" class="nodeSel" >title2/a> </div>`

I tried:
`$('div.dtNode:has(a)').css('background','red').addClass("test");
  $('div#menufirst:has(a)').addClass("test2").css('background','red');`

and css:
`div.dtNode[class*="nodeSel"] { background:green; }`

No effect. Could you please let me know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('div.dtNode:has(a.nodeSel)').addClass("newClass");​
```

This will add class named 'newClass' to the div with class 'dtNode' and contains 'a' tag with class 'nodeSel'

Final html of div will be:
     ............

Is this what you are looking for ?